# ActionScript 3: eventlisteners give 1009 error when not in frame1

Tags: actionscript-3

Thanks for the responses

*Note when the buttons and code are on Frame 1 it works perfectly *

All the script is in Frame 2, as are the two buttons. The only things not in frame to are the sprites I'm calling out of the library.

Ideally On frame 1 are navigation buttons - each button with a gotoAndPlay() call attached. When you click each one of these navigation buttons it takes you to a different page.

Each page has a a bunch of buttons. Each button, when clicked, plays a an audio, and adds/deletes children to the stage

My problem is any frame other than 1, (in this case 2) as soon as it lands on the frame even with appropriate buttons present it says it doesn't see them and balks at the even listeners.

I hope this makes sense.

----- Original post --------
I'm trying to understand how these things work. I have an empty frame in frame one. In that frame I have the code:

```
gotAndStop(2);
```

On frame 2 I have two buttons. I've added event listeners to them. This works fine. The problem is as soon as it hits frame two I get this error :

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null
> object reference.     at TesT_2_fla::MainTimeline/frame2()

The confusing thing is, when I have everything in Frame 1 it works like a charm.

On frame 2 the buttons are there already, if I put them in frame 1 it works, but in frame 2 no dice.

Can anyone explain what is happening and how I might be able to remedy this?

Comment: Could you put the code used in frame 2 ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you are writing the script in Frame 1. If nothing were in Frame 1, the user would automatically go to Frame 2, if you placed a stop(); on Frame 2. If you want to stop(); on Frame 1, you could add a button gotoAndStop(2) with an event listener. When placing script on a frame that may be also referenced in a later frame, use a separate script layer and extend that layer from the (key)frame on which the script first appears to the (key)frame on which it is also referenced. HTH

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I explained it very well. All the script is in Frame 2, as are the two buttons. The only things not in frame to are the sprites I'm calling out of the library.

Answer (score 0):

Ya know - after much searching I found a solution it does seem awfully cumberome. I added the following code (which I copied from someone elses post) Just in case any other noobs have a similiar problem

```
enter code here
      //listen for the Flash player's ENTER_FRAME event...
      this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame, false);

      //and call this checker function continually until all of the buttons are accounted for
      function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void 
      {
            if(and_btn != null && big_btn != null )
            {
                 and_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fAnd);
                 big_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fBig);

            //clean up the enter frame listener so that this function no longer gets called
            this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame, false);
            }
      }
```

It seems the code was running so fat the buttons didn't have a chance to populate the stage